# Python MemoryError w/ Plenty of RAM (64-bit)

Tags: python, memory, pandas, 64-bit

I am currently working with a large data file of dimension 15,883,912x105.  The storage size of this data set is just a shade under 10 GBs.  It is a fairly large set, but I am working on a box with 24 GB of RAM.

I am working on a 64-bit Windows machine ([Dell Precision T3500](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-t3500/pd) to be exact).  Further, this is all being done with a 64-bit Python install (v2.7.6 from [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/) 2.0.0).

The file actually reads in just fine, but when I subset to a two variables with under 500,000 rows, I am  encountering a `MemoryError`.  Specifically, I am trying to calculate the Gini coefficient (trapezoidal approximation) from a vector of data with the following code:

```
#Isolate test set
gini_test=gini.ix[1979]['adj_market_income']

#Define Gini calculator
def gini_trap(df,var,wt):
    '''Function takes incomes and weights, and returns the *weighted* Gini Coefficient.'''
    #Sort the df by income
    df.sort(columns=var,inplace=True)
    #Generate non-negative version
    inc=df[var].apply(lambda x: max(x,0.))
    #Calculate total weight
    tot_wt=df[wt].sum()
    #Calculate total weighted income
    tot_inc=(df[wt]*inc).sum()
    #Initialize share and cumulative variables
    wt_share=0
    inc_share=0
    cum_wt=0
    cum_inc=0
    #Initialize Gini value
    gini=0
    #For each record...
    for i,val in enumerate(inc):
        #...calculate the current records share of income and population...
        wt_share=df[wt].iloc[i]/tot_wt
        inc_share=(df[wt].iloc[i]*val)/tot_inc
        #...and augment the cumulative measures for income and population/update the gini value...
        cum_wt+=wt_share
        gini+=wt_share*(cum_inc+cum_inc+inc_share)
        cum_inc+=inc_share
    print cum_inc,cum_wt
    return 1-gini

print gini_trap(gini.ix[1979],'adj_market_income','wt')
```

There are a number of `MemoryError` issues here on Stack, but the common theme I have seen is to make sure one uses a 64-bit machine and has plenty of RAM (before getting into chunking and whatnot).  Any thoughts on what is happening here?

Comment: At what line does the MemoryError occur? You might want to try with a fraction of the data and memory_profiler, to see how many copies are made at which lines.

Comment: The `MemoryError` occurs when creating the weighted income variable (`inc_share`).  Indeed, trying to create this variable *outside* of the function yields the same error.  Using `memory_profiler` is a great idea, but I am afraid I am operating on an air-gapped machine and loading new packages onto it is non-trivial (both administratively and logistically).  Any other advice I can leverage in the meantime?

Comment: In the interests of full disclosure, I was able to generate the variables I needed by employing `numpy` operations (as opposed to operations on `pandas` objects), but I am still unclear on why I ran out of space to begin with.  Thoughts?

Comment: Numerical operations like this create temporary arrays to store the partial calculations. To save space, every numpy operation (e.g., add) takes a third parameter `out` to write into. Also, you could transform all your arrays into float32 to save space. Short of these, you'd probably have to abandon the in-memory numpy way of doing things in favour of element-wise operation.

Comment: A fair point, but the `numpy` operation (element-wise multiplication of two 1D arrays) actually worked.  It was the the multiplication of `pandas` **Series** objects that didn't fly...

Comment: pandas uses numpy internally. You may be able to do better by isolating out just the (numpy) array columns you actually need and working with them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as I said previously, the `numpy` operation worked.  I am currently wondering why the multiplication of the `pandas` **Series** objects did not.